Faster run by vectorizing
I'm looking to optimize this loop but I'm out of idea/skill.
I've tried to rewrite it with numba, jax with no success.
To implement conditions to not recompute things (little gain) but it's still around 30 sec by run.
I think vectorization is the way but I cant find a way to properly implement it. Any body could show me how to vectorize this knowing that selected inputs will have different length ?
#A coord xyz dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({"x" : np.random.uniform(100000.5,400000.5,69000),
                   "y" : np.random.uniform(100000.5,300000.5,69000),
                   "z" : np.random.uniform(-50.5,300.5, 69000),})

band_width, band_height, azi, max_distance, ang_tol = 100, 10, 60, 1000, 22.5


#float, float, float, int
x, y, z, idx = df['x'].values, df['y'].values, df[z_col].values, df.index.values
azi_rad = np.radians(azi)
cos_azi_rad, sin_azi_rad, tan_ang_tol_rad, ang_tol_rad = np.cos(azi_rad), np.sin(azi_rad), np.radians(ang_tol), np.tan(ang_tol_rad)
band_width, max_distance = 100, 1000

#will receive results by indentation later
res_select=np.empty_like(idx)

for id in idx :
    #origin point x,y,z
    xi, yi, zi = x[id], y[id], z[id]
    
    #cutting to smaller chunk
    cond_xy_cut = ((xi-max_distance) <= x) & (x <= (xi+max_distance)) & ((yi-max_distance) <= y) & (y <= (yi+max_distance))
    x_cut, y_cut, z_cut, w_cut, idx_cut = x[cond_xy_cut], y[cond_xy_cut], z[cond_xy_cut], weights[cond_xy_cut], idx[cond_xy_cut]

    #computing delta from origin point once for the 2 're-use' under
    dx,dy = x_cut-xi, y_cut-yi

    #rotating x,y around origin point at azi angle
    x_rotate = cos_azi_rad*(dx) - sin_azi_rad*(dy) + xi
    y_rotate = sin_azi_rad*(dx) + cos_azi_rad*(dy) + yi

    #computing new delta with x_rotate, y_rotate
    dx, dy = x_rotate-xi, y_rotate-yi

    #computing absolute arrays
    abs_dx, abs_dy = np.abs(dx), np.abs(dy)

    #computing delta_z
    dz = z_cut-zi

    #filtering selected rows
    cond_x = abs_dx <= band_width
    cond_y = (abs_dy <= max_distance) & (y_rotate >= yi)
    cond_z = np.abs(dz) <= band_height
    cond_cone = (tan_ang_tol_rad*abs_dy) >= np.sqrt((dx)**2 + (dz)**2)

    #summing conditions
    cond_sum = cond_x & cond_y & cond_z & cond_cone

    # pushing selected index in the result array
    res_select[id] = idx_cut[cond_sum & (idx_cut!=id)]

~ 27s runtime with 69000 values


EDIT :
So I rebuilt everything to try things again in Numba and went for a very very VERY ugly if elif else logic but it runs faster. And I know it can go even faster because I lake knowledge on nopython mode.
On the previous script i checked all conditions on the full array then keept only the ones that where True on every condition.
Now I'm checking the inverted conditions point by point and exclude the point as soon as one condition is false. I track results on array_check, a list initially full of zeros and when a point is True I add 1. At the end I only keep the 0 ones (yes I know it's an inverted logic for python but that's a draft). I switched back to the slow .append because I was stuck with read_only array when I tried to set item with res_select[id] = [...]. So even if I specify nopython=True, it falls back into nopyhton = False. I'm down to 4 seconds by run.
Next : How can I modify this function so it can fully run on nopython=True ? Knowing that my sub-arrays will have different length
len_idx = len(df.index.values)
@njit(nopython=True)
def numba_select_points_loop(idx, x, y, z, max_distance, cos_azi_rad, sin_azi_rad, len_idx, tan_ang_tol_rad) :
    #empty list initialisation
    res_select = []
    
    #loop starts
    for id in idx :
        xi, yi, zi = x[id], y[id], z[id] #origin points
        array_check = np.zeros(len_idx, dtype=np.int64)
        for i in range(len_idx) :
            if x[i] > (xi+max_distance) : #all conditions are inverted from previous script, aborting next conditions if condition met.
                array_check[i] += 1
            elif x[i] < (xi-max_distance) :
                array_check[i] += 1
            elif y[i] < (yi-max_distance) :
                array_check[i] += 1
            elif y[i] > (yi+max_distance) :
                array_check[i] += 1
            elif np.abs(z[i]-zi) > band_height :
                array_check[i] += 1
            else :
                x_rotate = cos_azi_rad*(x[i]-xi) - sin_azi_rad*(y[i]-yi) + xi
                y_rotate = sin_azi_rad*(x[i]-xi) + cos_azi_rad*(y[i]-yi) + yi
                if np.abs(x_rotate-xi) > band_width :
                    array_check[i] += 1
                elif np.abs(y_rotate-yi) > max_distance :
                    array_check[i] += 1
                elif y_rotate < yi :
                    array_check[i] += 1
                elif (tan_ang_tol_rad*np.abs(y_rotate-yi)) < np.sqrt(np.abs(x_rotate-xi)**2 + np.abs(z[i]-zi)**2) :
                    array_check[i] += 1
                elif id == i :
                    array_check[i] += 1

        res_select.append( [id] + [ arr for arr,b in zip(idx,array_check) if b==0 ] ) # I added the corresponding id in front in case numba runs asynchronous.

    return res_select

~ 4-5 seconds with 69000 values

"I've tried to rewrite it with numba, jax with no success" - what was the problem? Also, try to make minimal, reproducible example

I deleted my jax and numba code. Jax I learned that doing the same thing in numpy and jax while running only on CPU result in Jax being way slower than synchronous numpy computation. I used jnp only and didn't tried lax. For Numba the loops were fast until I got stuck in the conditions while trying to translate the "&" (even while trying to workaround with np.bitwise_and) but the code became too complicated for numba paralellization. As I cant even simplify my own code on numpy I think there is a lot of things I may have missed trying these two libraries.

Maybe all you need is solve your jax/numba problem? Narrow it down - which operations you have problem with and put as separate question/s.   I do not see why numba wouldn't work here.

As you say, code is complicated, not only for you, for us even more. After month you will strugle to read it too. Introduce some functions, give more descriptive names, just learn a bit about clean code practices. Best code is self-explanatory (without need of comments) - not always possible to achieve, but for sure you could remove more than half of those comments. For example #computing delta_z and dz = z_cut-zi - just rename to delta_z and remove comment. Or don't rename since dz is found very often everywhere and means the same

No, all functions have been removed in favor of inline coding to not heat up the overhead on 69000 call of the same function and passing different values. Comments have been added for the forum so you understand what's the purpose of every block. The main purpose is like looking in a telescope to the horizon at, for e.g. 10° from North (azi value) and I want to collect the index of every point that intersects my view. The telescope has ang_tol, band_width, band_view and max_distance in parameters.

Since you are not planning to prepare example, all I can do now is suggest to make friends with line_profiler and find your bottleneck

Thanks but already done that and every line runs the same amount of time, approximately. There is no real bottleneck but I assume as res_select gets bigger by receiving selected index arrays it slows down the second half of the run. I can see that decreasing speed at around 30000 to 40000. I may loose some seconds but not quite significant. I tried initially with an res_select.append([x,x,x]) method from an empty res_select list but the res_select[id] = [x,x,x] is faster.

@Spon Can you please edit your question and add some sample values (df, weights, azi, etc...)

@Andrej done sir! I don't know if np.random.uniform is the proper function to use but I meant 69000 random x,y,z

@Spon I ran your code as is (just removed the weights to able it to start) and on my computer amd 5700x it takes ~7 seconds. On what hardware are you running  it?

I have a 16 GB RAM and I7 evo. Sorry about weights, I dont have implemented yet...

Andrej, @dankal444 I gave another shot to numba and tried to modify my logic with something quite unconventional, the new code is in the "edit" section. I lake skills in numba so I fall back in nopython=False but that's a first step.

@Spon to address different-length and avoid using list: You can make your array-based list. Assume some initial length (e.g. 10/100/1000) and then keep track of the true size of the data inside. Before appending/extending the list make sure you have enough space. If not - create new array-list 1.5x/2x larger.

You can also check which initial size and which multiplier gives you best performance. Sidenote: you can add signatures to speed-up numba compilation, eg. "float64[:,:](int64[:])" is signature for function that takes 1D int64 array and returns 2D float64 array

One thing I would do is to eliminate the loop over each index by applying calculations to all points at once using broadcasting.
https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.broadcasting.html
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/constants.html#numpy.newaxis
Also, you're missing band_height and np.radians(ang_tol), np.tan(ang_tol_rad) can be combined in np.tan(np.radians(ang_tol)).
NumPy is designed for large array operations at once, so try to minimize repetitive array slicing in the loop.
# Inputs
x, y, z, idx = df['x'].values, df['y'].values, df[z_col].values, df.index.values
azi_rad = np.radians(azi)
cos_azi_rad, sin_azi_rad = np.cos(azi_rad), np.sin(azi_rad)
tan_ang_tol_rad = np.tan(np.radians(ang_tol))
band_width, max_distance, band_height = 100, 1000, 50  # Add missing variable band_height, example value

# Pre-compute rotation values once (without loop)
dx_total = x[:, np.newaxis] - x[np.newaxis, :]
dy_total = y[:, np.newaxis] - y[np.newaxis, :]
dz_total = z[:, np.newaxis] - z[np.newaxis, :]

# Apply azimuth rotation to all points
x_rotate_total = cos_azi_rad * dx_total - sin_azi_rad * dy_total + x[np.newaxis, :]
y_rotate_total = sin_azi_rad * dx_total + cos_azi_rad * dy_total + y[np.newaxis, :]

# Compute absolute values
abs_dx_total = np.abs(x_rotate_total - x[:, np.newaxis])
abs_dy_total = np.abs(y_rotate_total - y[:, np.newaxis])

# Filter conditions (all points at once)
cond_x = abs_dx_total <= band_width
cond_y = (abs_dy_total <= max_distance) & (y_rotate_total >= y[:, np.newaxis])
cond_z = np.abs(dz_total) <= band_height
cond_cone = (tan_ang_tol_rad * abs_dy_total) >= np.sqrt(dx_total**2 + dz_total**2)

# Combine all conditions
cond_total = cond_x & cond_y & cond_z & cond_cone

# Remove diagonal (self-comparisons)
np.fill_diagonal(cond_total, False)

# Results
res_select = [idx[cond_total[id]] for id in range(len(idx))]


Thanks but computing shape 69000x69000 3 times is not the best strategy for my code as it will depend on available memory of the computer. MemoryError: Unable to allocate 36.2 GiB for an array with shape (69707, 69707) and data type float64.

Thanks for the broadcasting link by the way! I've learned about the stretch when operating 1d array with a value (e.g. : [x,x,x] + y). Do you know if the 'stretching' costs memory ?

Yes, it would only make it worse in this case.

There are numerous ways to increase the speed of code, using numpy arrays over standard lists for calculations is usually always faster (as you have already attempted).
-Secondary since your calculations are independent from each other (calculating distance a does not affect the calculation for distance b) you could try to parallelize your code by e.g. hyperthreading. \
-Tertiary, from my background in industrial engineering I know alot about the need to calculate distances. The trick here is not to (as you stated) implement conditions to NOT recompute things. Rather it is often way faster to look at exactly which points you do need to recompute!

As I couldn't comment on another answer, about memory issues; Please note that you do not need your entire 69000x69000 array, rather half of the array is quite useless as it contains duplicate information. (this does assume that the distance from point a-b is the same as distance b-a).

you're right but even the half might be 15+Gb that I will have to compute 3 times (x,y,z). On the dataset I'm using there are some redundant xy combination so I could compute only on unique f"{x}_{y}" key but my code has to be able to manage larger datasets with x,y variations in z, the "key strategy" would be useless
